# How do a run a bash script on save in NetBeans?

Tags: bash, netbeans, ant, shell, netbeans6.5

I am using NetBeans 6.5 and whenever I save a LessCSS file I would like to run less compiler to compile it to native css. How do I go about achieving this? 
Many Thanks.
Ravi

**EDIT**: I can do a build file as Kim recommended below. I am searching for a solution where I can run an external command. So the question now is How Do I Run an External Command using Ant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be on save? Instead, you could create a custom project (with a custom build file) and just put it into that build file.

Comment: Yes, it need not be on save. A build file should work. How do I add a build file to a PHP Project in NetBeans? Would ANT be the only option as my needs seem simple enough right now? Thanks.

Comment: This link http://ant.apache.org/manual/CoreTasks/exec.html is broken